# : Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\class-wp-http-curl.php on line 240

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying  to import a 4.5 MB WXR (XML file) in a WordPress theme. After increasing the size of max_execution_time, max_input_time memory_limit = 1 meg, I still get the same error.

Comment: try posting the solution if something worked for you so the future users can benefit from it.

Answer (score 2):

Navigate to this file in your wordpress directory: wp-includes/deprecated.php, this line in (deprecated) wp_get_http() function:

@set_time_limit ( 60 );
just comment out this line by adding "//"

Answer (score -1):

you can try to change upload_max_filesize = 64M

Comment: have you ever installed php_xmlprc and php_xsl extensions?

Comment: i am using xampp as localhost

Comment: i'm not familiar with xampp, but i think is like others environment. So, look for php extensions in xammp control panel and enable it.

Answer (score -1):

in wp-includes folder find this file and add on top.

```
set_time_limit (0);
```

it will solve your issue.